# Imported sys module successfully but sys not defined (ATOM IDE)

Tags: python, atom-editor, nameerror, sys

I am a new Atom user.

I am trying to set a higher recursion limit by using sys.setrecursionlimit(). Here is my code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
```

I ran the code line by line and sys was successfully imported. However, the second line returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\inval\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\2021529-30540-1qngqnd.ejyu", line 4, in <module>
    sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

I have tried this with other packages like math and it works fine:

```
import math
print(math.pi/2)
```

I have also tried the sys code on Jupyter Notebook and Spyder. No issues there.

Any fellow Atom peeps to the rescue?

Comment: Atom has no means to run code, so you are likely using a third-party package that adds this functionality. The question is which one is it?

Comment: Hi @idleberg thanks for the response. I downloaded the script package to run my code.

Answer (score 1):

just thought I close the thread with an update. Just seemed to be a bug in Atom as it didn't work for one file but worked for another. Its all smooth sailing already. Thanks to all.